# Multiple Solver Jobs with differing Solver Configurations

Tags: timefold

I am trying to implement a queue like system for Solver Jobs.

I'd prefer to relegate the "scheduling" of jobs to TimeFold. So,i'm using the SolverManager to add jobs, and maintaining a separate state that is updated on start and final best score.

I wish that process were a bit easier, and embedded with SolverManager.

Anyways, my question: Is there any way for me to give each Solver Job it's own Solver Config? As if I were to create Solvers manually, I could give them their own configuration. I'm primarily interested in the ability to do this so that I can support varying problem sizes: "turn-on" partitioning, modify terminations, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. No, if you only want one `SolverManager` instance.
Yes, if you don't mind having multiple, one for each config.

Some parameters, like termination, will likely be [overridable in the future](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/150), but for vastly different configs (such as configs that introduce extra move selectors etc.), different `SolverManager` instances will continue to be necessary.

Also note that we do not currently support [multiple instances of SolverManager when using Quarkus](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/351) and Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks! SolverFactory etc... is making a bit more sense now. This is a separate question, but I'm trying to figure out if theres a way to "terminate" a solver job, without dispatching the "bestSolution" consumer. Any insight for that?